# how to upgrade dart to higher version 2.14+

Tags: macos, dart, homebrew

I have already installed dart in mac(Intel Chip):

```
$ brew info dart                                                                                                                            ‹ruby-2.7.2›
dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 2.14.4, HEAD
SDK
https://dart.dev
Conflicts with:
  dart-beta (because dart-beta ships the same binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/HEAD (868 files, 506.2MB) *
  Built from source on 2022-09-04 at 22:53:21
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.14.4 (822 files, 543.3MB)
  Built from source on 2022-08-20 at 18:17:47
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.18 (918 files, 677.8MB)
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/HEAD/Formula/dart.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
(base)
```

now I want to upgrade the dart version to `2.18`, but I did not found the new version of formula:

```
$ brew install dart@2.18                                                                                                                    ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Warning: No available formula with the name "dart@2.18". Did you mean dart@2.1, dart@2.8, dart@2.13, dart@2.12, dart@2.10, dart@2.2, dart@2.7, dart@2.6, dart@2.5, dart@2.4, dart@2.3, dart@2.9 or dart@2.0?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.1        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.12       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.7        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.4        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.0
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.8        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.10       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.6        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.3
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.13       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.2        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.5        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.9
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install dart-lang/dart/dart@2.1
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
(base)
```

is it possible to install higher version of dart in macos, I have tried to searching from google but still found no one talk about this issue.  what should I do to upgrade the dart? I have already tried the brew upgrade command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [dart-sdk 2.18.5](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/dart-sdk.rb), which is pretty well maintained.

We dont have dart in homebrew-core due to the reason detailed in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/103222#issuecomment-1206530213).